# Git Permission Denied when checking out a branch

Tags: git

I am having a git issue with a specific folder when trying to checkout to the master branch from my events-feature branch. Below is what is happening in the command line. No code is being changed during the command line inputs. At the end of my second git status the folder lib/partials has been deleted.

```
~/Desktop/climbingTheWeb/climbers-hub (events-feature)
$ git status
On branch events-feature
nothing to commit, working directory clean

~/Desktop/climbingTheWeb/climbers-hub (events-feature)
$ git checkout master
fatal: cannot create directory at 'lib/partials': Permission denied

~/Desktop/climbingTheWeb/climbers-hub (events-feature)
$ git status
lib/partials/createEvent.jade: Permission denied
lib/partials/event.jade: Permission denied
lib/partials/login.jade: Permission denied
lib/partials/navbar.jade: Permission denied
lib/partials/register.jade: Permission denied
lib/partials/search.jade: Permission denied
lib/partials/welcome.jade: Permission denied
On branch events-feature
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   gulpfile.js
    modified:   lib/js/config.js
    deleted:    lib/js/createEventController.js
    modified:   lib/js/eventController.js
    deleted:    models/event.js
    deleted:    public/index.html
    deleted:    public/partials/createEvent.html
    deleted:    public/partials/createEventForm.html

    no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: So use `ls -l` to look at the file permissions on that directory.

Comment: change the file permissions , commit/stash or changes then you are done